# Compose Cartopy projective transformations

Tags: matplotlib, gis, cartopy, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

With this simple example:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

import cartopy.crs
import cartopy.feature.nightshade
import cartopy.mpl.geoaxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class Hemisphere(NamedTuple):
    coord: tuple[float, float]
    crs: cartopy.crs.Orthographic
    ax: cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes

    @classmethod
    def make(
        cls,
        coord: tuple[float, float],
        figure: plt.Figure,
    ) -> 'Hemisphere':
        crs = cartopy.crs.Orthographic(
            central_longitude=coord[0],
            central_latitude=coord[1],
        )
        ax = figure.add_subplot(projection=crs)
        return cls(coord=coord, crs=crs, ax=ax)

    def plot(
        self,
        night: cartopy.feature.nightshade.Nightshade,
    ) -> None:
        self.ax.stock_img()
        self.ax.add_feature(night)
        self.ax.gridlines()


def plot(
    home_coord: tuple[float, float],
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig: plt.Figure = plt.figure()
    home_hemi = Hemisphere.make(coord=home_coord, figure=fig)
    night = cartopy.feature.nightshade.Nightshade()
    home_hemi.plot(night=night)
    return fig


def main() -> None:
    home_coord = -80, 40
    plot(home_coord=home_coord)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: shaded earth]

I want to be able to rotate the depiction of the Earth such that the sunset-line is vertical, implying that the axial tilt of the Earth matches what it actually is in the solar system. I need to preserve scale and the location of home at the `central_` point. Roughly this would look like

[image: manually rotated]

I believe this information to already be embedded in the calculations in Cartopy's `nightshade.py` - the `Nightshade` feature has a `crs` set to `rotated_pole`. Of course, if I initialise the axes to *only* use `night.crs`, then the shadow is correctly aligned but I lose my `Orthographic`:

[image: shadow aligned]

I want to compose the two and have an orthographic plot with the aligned sunset shadow. I've hunted around, and the closest I can find to composition in Cartopy is `InterProjectionTransform`, but this has several issues:

- it isn't actually a Cartopy `Projection`, but instead a matplotlib `Transform`
- it requires that you already have axes initialised - which means you can't use it to initialise axes.

I've looked, and there's no rotation angle parameter to `Orthographic`, nor does there seem to be the equivalent of an `InterProjection` for proper Cartopy projections.

I'd prefer to figure out something that uses Cartopy projection code if at all possible, avoiding mucking about in the lower matplotlib transformation code; though I don't know how practical that is. I'd also prefer to leverage what `Nightshade` has already done.